# How does static site generator work with a CMS like wordpress

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, static-site, gridsome

I have been exploring using Vue for wordpress frontend, and I came across so many different technologies, like Nuxt.js, Gridsome, VuePress, and they help to create sites into SPA, SSR, or static sites. I really like these ideas, because I want to move into modern frontends instead of using the WordPress default. So I am looking into headless WordPress.

After some research, I think I kind of like Gridsome with Wordpress, as Gridsome helps to build static site by compiling content from CMS and templates at build time.

So I have a very newbie question, CMS like wordpress gets updated everyday by users, to update pages, add new posts etc, does that mean you need to build the site every time people add some content to the CMS?

I'm going to build a sort of internal portal, with WordPress and I want to try out Vue, so with all these technologies out there, I am lost at what framework best suit my project with dynamic content.

Any suggestions or insights? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> So I have a very newbie question, CMS like wordpress gets updated everyday by > users, to update pages, add new posts etc, does that mean you need to build the  > site every time people add some content to the CMS?

Yes that's the concept of a statically generated site.
Still it's a choice of how you design your application.
Normally when a new post is created there can be an event / webhook triggering a build job which would automatically build and deploy the page with the latest post.

Still you can have in your deployed application client side Vue components which call the API directly to retrieve data and display it. For example for the comments it could make sense to do this.

Netlify is a good example which has the whole static site generation eased up with a nice CI / CD which can be triggered automatically as soon as your site. They also have a CMS which works on top of markdown files. As soon as a changed / new markdown file is commited to the repository it triggers a build to deploy the latest version of the page.

I hope this helps.

Thanks and best regards,
ewatch

Comment: Hi @ewatch, I also read about Netlify, they indeed provide a webhook to rebuild when a post is saved. However, we have a constraint of using Netlify for hosting, so we are stuck with our own internal server to host the app. So the webhook part will be difficulty I guess. I am now trying nuxt to build a universal app to do partial server side rendering.

Comment: when you say I can use client side API to retrieve data and display it, I thought all that logic is done during build process, so the static side will not retrieve any new content from CMS? Did I miss something here?

Comment: https://gridsome.org/docs/guide-comments/
when you look on this page they propose for example also to integrate external services like disqus. But if only a specific part of your page should still be dynamic you can keep it dynamic and make a client vue component which communicates with an API.
This still has a better performance as if the whole site would always need to be rendered from server etc.

Comment: https://en.support.wordpress.com/webhooks/
if you look on this page Wordpress offers webhooks, so that you can notify another system when a new post is released. With this you could for example trigger "gridsome build" on a Jenkins server or something like that.